# How to create an infinite loop with a text file? (Append text file and read/get the next line)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to find out the percentage of instagram users that have a certain number of followers. This program reads a file to get the first instagram user and takes its list of followers and puts it in the same text file. This is where I'm stuck. I need to get the program to reread the file, delete the first line it just read, and get the next text line.

Basically what I'm trying to do is read the text file, append the text file with the output I'm given, delete the line just read, and read the new line over and over and over again. An infinite loop.

```
 file = open("followers.txt","r+")
 #start username
 data = ""
 lines = file.readlines()
 a = 0
 b = 0
 c = 0
 d = 0

 for line in lines:
     data = line.strip()

     # Obtain profile metadata

     profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, data)

     #for every followee in the accounts list of followers

     for followee in profile.get_followers():

         file = open("followers.txt", "a+")

         #username = followees[followee]

         username = followee.username

         file.write(username + "\n")

         profile1 = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, username)

         followers = profile1.followers

         if followers < 1000:
              a+=1
         if followers >= 1000 & followers <= 250000:
              b+=1
         if followers > 250000 & followers <= 1000000:
              c+=1
         if followers > 1000000:
              d+=1

    print(username)
```

file.close()

Comment: doing this with text file is very ,very slow . you want a database.
PS: your algorithm is flawed,  there are large numbers of isolated social network, which is not guaranteed to be find out by your algorithm

Comment: How would I integrate a database into this project? Could you send me to a tutorial that would help? Also what do you mean by "there are large numbers of isolated social network, which is not guaranteed to be find out by your algorithm"

Comment: sorry i cant find solid proof  or reference on the point of "large number" , but isolated network do exist.  eg. three people follow each other but not anyone out of these three

Comment: I see what you mean and I'll do some research to figure out how to fix the flaw later. I would like to know how to do what my original question asked if you know how to do it.

Comment: and you can try "sqlite tutorial python "  on as searching keyword, Sqlite is a single  file based  database , suitable for the replacement  on text file